# Why is the output "0x7ffffcf9a010"?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string cars[4] = {"Volvo", "BMW", "Ford", "Mazda"};
    cars[0] = "Opel";
    cout << cars;
    return 0;
}
```

Why is it returning `0x7ffffcf9a010` when I output it?

Comment: `cout` doesn't know how to print arrays. Use a loop to print each string individually.

Comment: it is displaying the memory address of the first member of the array

Comment: What is you purpose when you assign `cars[0] = "Opel";`? What do you _expect_ when outputting `cars`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo well while learning through w3 schools, i came through this code and when i tried to edit it a bit, i wanted to know the output but it outputted some pointer variable so i was little confused but yeah, now i get it why it was happening, thanks in advance :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , oh, fine!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will output that, the strange number you see is the address of the starting of the first element of the array, cars is implicitly converted to a pointer. By itself, it's an array rather than a pointer.

You want to do this,

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string cars[4] = {"Volvo", "BMW", "Ford", "Mazda"};
    cars[0] = "Opel";
    //cout << cars[0]; // To print the first element
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        // To print all the elements one by one with a new line in between each element
        cout<<cars[i] << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cars` is *implicitly converted* to a pointer. By itself it's an array rather than a pointer.

Comment: "*`cars` is the pointer to the first string in the array*" - no, it is not a pointer. It is an array, period. It would be more accurate to say that it *decays* into a pointer to the 1st string. Not quite the same thing as *being* a pointer.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the in-accurate wordings, I have corrected accordingly.

Comment: yeah, so it means that when i output using cout , it will return a pointer variable always and i have to use loops instead of using cout to get a list.

Comment: Yes, you will have to do that.
You can also do  cout << cars[0]; if you want to specifically print a specific index element

Answer (score 0):

Output the name of raw array will return the first address of string array, which is the first element address too. Here's an example with std::string and int raw array.

```
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    std::string str[] = {"This", "is", "a", "string"};
    std::cout << str << std::endl;    //output 0xc3585ff5b0

    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::cout << arr << std::endl;    //output 0xc3585ff590
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake, answer has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

It outputs the hexadecimal address of the first element(0 index) of the array. Since array is a data structure that's why it outputs its address.

To correct the code you need to do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main() {
    std::string cars[4] = {"Volvo", "BMW", "Ford", "Mazda"};
    cars[0] = "Opel";
    
    char string1[100]={"C-style string."};
    std::cout << *cars<<"\n";
    
    
    std::cout<<string1; // does not show hexadecimal address but why?
    return 0;
}
```

Now this code will output 'Opel' as you required. The little asterisk next to the cars is known as the indirection operator. It is used to access the value the pointer is pointing to. Your confusion might be coming from the char array which can be outputted in one go using std::cout but the char array is an exception to the rule, the string array is not the same.
Note(it is better use std::array and std::vector for modern C++ programming instead of the old fashioned array. )

Comment: ok, thnx :) , but i don't really use std::array that much cauz i get confused sometimes , so yeah...